# SphinxQL compare json attributes

Tags: sphinx

I have a json string that looks like this:

```
{"mo":[{"from":800,"to":1100},{"from":1400,"to":1700}],"di":[{"from":800,"to":1100},{"from":1400,"to":1700}],"do":[{"from":800,"to":1100},{"from":1400,"to":1700}],"mi":[{"from":800,"to":1100}],"fr":[{"from":800,"to":1300}],"so":[],"sa":[]}
```

The mysql field that containts this json string is declared as `sql_attr_json` in the config.

The following `WHERE` condition works fine:

```
WHERE json.mo[0].from < 1100
```

however, the following does not:

```
WHERE json.mo[0].from < json.mo[0].to
```

it results in:

```
sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected IDENT near 'json.mo[0].to
```

Why is that? I am trying to implement a check for opening hours but unfortunately I am having a really hard time doing so, I tried a dozen of different approaches and nothing seems to work.

**Update:**

I am also trying to do:

```
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%H%i') between json.mo[0].from and json.mo[0].to)
```

that results in

```
sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected '(' near '(NOW(),'%H%i')) between json.mo[0].from and json.mo[0].to)
```

Even a basic

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%H%i') < 1050
```

results to the same error

```
 Sphinx expr: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end near '(NOW(),'%H%i') < 1050'
```

As a workaround I also tried

```
SELECT CONCAT(HOUR(NOW()), MINUTE(NOW())) currentTime;
```

but that results in

```
sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FROM or ',' near 'currentTime'
```

In MySQL it works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just not implemented yet. Try the following workaround:

```
mysql> select *, INTEGER(j.mo[0].to) - INTEGER(j.mo[0].from) diff from rt where diff > 0\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  id: 1
   s:
   j: {"mo":[{"from":800,"to":1100},{"from":1400,"to":1700}],"di":[{"from":800,"to":1100},{"from":1400,"to":1700}],"do":[{"from":800,"to":1100},{"from":1400,"to":1700}],"mi":[{"from":800,"to":1100}],"fr":[{"from":800,"to":1300}],"so":[],"sa":[]}
diff: 300
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Works fine for me in Manticore Search (fork of Sphinx), should work fine in Sphinx too.

Comment: Hi, thanks that seems to work just fine. Unfortunately there is another part that does not appear to be working, I updated my question. I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Neither DATE_FORMAT nor any function for string concatenation is implemented, so I'm afraid it's impossible to compare %H%i from json with current %H%i. Try storing timestamp in the json and compare with NOW(). Or submit a feature request.

Comment: Urgh.. Same goes for your engine? Is BETWEEN supported?

Comment: Yes, BETWEEN is supported. Yes, Manticore Search also doesn't have a function for string concatenation.